# Side penetration on an underground pull box?

Tags: underground

Can you make a side penetration in an underground quazite pull box 25"x30"x12"? If yes or no what codes back it up?

Comment: Unless you are using rigid metal conduit and/or a concrete cover, (both fairly expensive ways to keep conduit shallow but protected) your conduits should be deeper than that anyway, and can enter in the usual way from the bottom.

Comment: Rather than being directly in code, the code tends to specify that you use a listed device in accordance with the manufacturers instructions, and those would specify if you could put a hole in the side or not. Free tip from experience - come into the box from below with 45's rather than 90's if at all possible.

Answer (score 2):

These pull boxes are open bottom (most of them) and are meant to have the underground conduits elbowed up into them since they're only 12" deep. Some might have side knockouts but I haven't run across any. The sides aren't intended to have holes knocked out in them. hope this helps. I don't have code backup, only installation backup.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the model. The cast models have recesses that start about 8” down then the recessed channel goes to the bottom. These both in plastic and concrete can be entered from the side but if no recess I would say no.